# jquery ui autocomplete combobox no dropdown visible

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, combobox

I want to include a jquery ui autocomplete combobox as shown on http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox. Hovever my combobox was just a drop down menu until I included jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css into my html file- I now have a Autocomplete (typing) function but no dropdown menu anymore.  Is there anything else I need to include to get the autocomplete functionality along with a dropdown menu?

I have the following scripts and css files included:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--my own code-->
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynamic2.js"></script> <!--my own code-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootswatch.js"></script>
```

I included into my html file:

```
        <div class="ui-widget">             
          <input id="tags" />
        </div>
```

into my css file:

```
.ui-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* adjust styles for IE 6/7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
}
.ui-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
```

and into my js:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var input,
                self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                    .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                    .insertAfter( select );

            input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            $( "<a>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .appendTo( wrapper )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $( this ).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
        }
    });
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

I also tried to create a separate file with just that autocomplete combobox but that does  the same thing- either just autocomplete without dropbox or just dropbox and no possibility to write text.

I spent a lot of time on this already and feel incredibly stupid because it seems to work fine for everyone else so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. drop down not showing on local machine but showing online.

I do not understand what you mean that

```
                      .ui-autocomplete {
                       z-index: 10000;
                       }
```

solved your problem.

The solution for me was like  Abhijit Mazumder above pointed out. Missing of images that 
are being referred in the css file

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

when working on local computer.

This referenced css file keeps referring to images such as 
url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png") which i believe is available 
online but not in local computer.

So that is how the drop down image keeps missing.

I solved this by downloading the jquery autocomplete ui and it had the images in their folder as i needed.

It was a bit tricky because the downloaded autocomplete ui zip file has no drop down button.

So i used the code from jquery website auto complete feature because it had drop down feature but used the file jquery-ui.css from downloaded zip file.

It was quite a walk about but hope someone else will benefit.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by adding to my css file a z-index style for the autocomplete.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Remember to set a higher value for the `z-index` if it is necessary. Just for the record I have something like this in the HTML file

```
<div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="employee">Employee:</label>
   <input id="employee" type="text" name="employee" />
</div>
```